# How to get the se semantic meaning of a word/phrase

Tags: python, nlp

Hi guys I need help on a thing, currently I'm working on a project where I have to find the semantic meaning of a word /phrase. For example
Hi, hello, good morning should return regards etc...
Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think you should try to search more on `python nltk` NLTK- Natural Language Toolkit. I'm sure you'll find it there, I've done this before, I'll update

Comment: This is not semantics, but pragmatics: the function of a phrase in a conversation. In principle, this is a tough problem unless you're working in a restricted domain, and I would say it's not possible, as there is no scheme for coding the meaning of phrases (semantics) or their function (pragmatics).

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit vague, but here are two ideas that might help:

### 1. WordNet

**[WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/)** is a lexical database that provides synonyms, categorisations and to some extent the 'semantic meaning' of English words. Here is the [web interface](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn) to explore the database. Here is how to use it [via NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html).

**Example:**

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

# get all possible meanings of a word. e.g. "welcome" has two possible meanings as a noun, three meanings as a verb and one meaning as an adjective    
wn.synsets('welcome')
# output: [Synset('welcome.n.01'), Synset('welcome.n.02'), Synset('welcome.v.01'), Synset('welcome.v.02'), Synset('welcome.v.03'), Synset('welcome.a.01')]

# get the definition of one of these meanings:
wn.synset('welcome.n.02').definition()
# output: 'a greeting or reception'

# get the hypernym of the specific meaning, i.e. the more abstract category it belongs to
wn.synset('welcome.n.02').hypernyms()
# output: [Synset('greeting.n.01')]
```

### 2. Zero-shot-classification

**[HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/) Transformers and zero-shot classification**: You can also use a pre-trained deep learning model to classify your text. In this case, you need to manually create labels for all possible different meanings you are looking for in your texts. e.g.: ["greeting", "insult", "congratulation"].
Then you can use the deep learning model to predict which label (broadly speaking 'semantic meaning') is the most adequate for your text.

**Example:**

```
# pip install transformers==3.1.0  # pip install in terminal
from transformers import pipeline

classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification")

sequence = "Hi, I welcome you to this event"
candidate_labels = ["greeting", "insult", "congratulation"]

classifier(sequence, candidate_labels)

# output: {'sequence': 'Hi, I welcome you to this event',
# 'labels': ['greeting', 'congratulation', 'insult'],
# 'scores': [0.9001138210296631, 0.09858417510986328, 0.001302019809372723]}
```

=> Each of your labels received a score and the label with the highest score would be the "semantic meaning" of your text.

Here is an interactive [web application](https://huggingface.co/zero-shot/) to see what the library does without coding. Here is a [Jupyter notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jocViLorbwWIkTXKwxCOV9HLTaDDgCaw?usp=sharing) which demonstrates how to use it in Python. You can just copy-paste code from the notebook.

Comment: Hello, not OP but wanted to comment to say thank you for this. I'm currently trying to implement some sort of semantic analysis to identify when a sentence is analytical, contradictory or synthetic. Both the zero-shot learning and WorldNet are good starting points as well as the PropBank corpus for labelling. Would you have any suggestions on how to identify these sentences @Moritz?

Comment: What are the classes "analytical, contradictory, synthetic" based on? Is this based on specific literature and/or a training dataset, or categories that you came up with for your use-case?

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown any effort to do your own code, but here is a small example.

```
words = ['hello','hi','good morning']
x = input('Word here: ')
if x.lower() in words:
      print('Regards')
```